# Remove characters from a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset as follows,

```
[1] "21/12/16, 14:25:10: abcd                     
[2] "21/12/16, 14:25:14: 1234            
[3] "21/12/16, 14:25:22: XXX           
[4] "21/12/16, 14:25:30: YYY          
[5] "21/12/16, 14:25:47: ZZZ
```

Date variable has all the dates in the above dataset as,

`> head(date)
[1] "21/12/16" "21/12/16" "21/12/16" "21/12/16" "21/12/16"`

Time variable has all times from the dataset as,

`> head(time)
[1] "14:25" "14:25" "14:25" "14:25" "14:25"`

Now I want the dataset to be modified as,

```
[1] abcd                     
[2] 1234            
[3] XXX           
[4] YYY          
[5] ZZZ
```

How can we do this? I tried gsub but no use. Can someone help me out here.

Comment: What do you mean with that modification? Where does that come from? Do you only want to have the last column? The dataset you post in the beginning, what is it called? Is it a data.frame?

Comment: @KenS. It's not a data frame. It's a character. A whole text file has been read into R.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't completely precise as to the expected behavior, but for the dataset that you've supplied, splitting on ":" and taking the fourth element of the resulting vector will get the desired result. You should think about the use case and whether you can rely on that working in general, however. e.g. Will there always be exactly three colons before the string you want? Will the string you want never contain a colon? etc.

Also, I think you're missing a closing quote mark in your rows.

Answer (score 1):

```
readLines(con = textConnection("21/12/16, 14:25:10: abcd
21/12/16, 14:25:14: 1234
21/12/16, 14:25:22: XXX
21/12/16, 14:25:30: YYY
21/12/16, 14:25:47: ZZZ")) -> text_file_lines

text_file_lines
## [1] "21/12/16, 14:25:10: abcd" "21/12/16, 14:25:14: 1234"
## [3] "21/12/16, 14:25:22: XXX"  "21/12/16, 14:25:30: YYY" 
## [5] "21/12/16, 14:25:47: ZZZ" 

# built-in
# somewhat forgiving regex replace
sub("^[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+/[[:digit:]]+,[[:space:]]+[[:digit:]]+:[[:digit:]]+:[[:digit:]]+:[[:space:]]", "", text_file_lines)
## [1] "abcd" "1234" "XXX"  "YYY"  "ZZZ" 

# external pkg
# this matches from last : onward and extracts the bits you want
stringi::stri_match_last_regex(text_file_lines, ": ([[:print:]]+)$")[,2]
## [1] "abcd" "1234" "XXX"  "YYY"  "ZZZ"
```